# Add script only once for Shortcode and Widget

Tags: wordpress

I've written a plugin which loads a JS library in a WordPress post. I'm using a WordPress shortcode to detect a call to the plugin like this : `[myplugin class="abc"]`.

So basically everytime the user writes `[myplugin ...]`, my plugins transforms this string into a `<p class="abc">` tag and I'm enqueuing a remote JS script which parses the `<p>` tag.
I would like to allow the same behavior for a widget sidebar, so the user can write `<p class="abc">` in a `text` widget. All I need is the JS to be loaded.

Rather than loading this JS lib in the `text` widget + in every post, I'd rather embed my script only once, every time the WordPress is loaded.

Is saw in akismet code source that they are using the `init` hook. Is that the right hook to use ?

Comment: [How to load JS like a WP Master](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code in your plugin (`your_plugin.php`)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts' );
function load_my_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script',  plugins_url( '/js/my_script.js' , __FILE__ ) );
}
```

Here, the `my_script.js` file could be in your plugin's folder like `your_Plugin/js/my_script.js`.

[Read more on Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: I know how to enqueue a script, what i was asking is the name of the Wordpress hook I should use in order to load them everytime the Wordpress is loaded. I've solved my probem using the `init` hook + loading this JS in the footer (to be sure that every other parsing is done).

Comment: WordPress uses `wp_enqueue_scripts` to add scripts on the front end.